# C# SQL Query Producing Different Results than Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

```
SELECT  
   wl.WatchListId, wl.Code, wl.[Description], wl.DateCreated,
   wl.CreatedBy, wl.DateModified, wl.ModifiedBy,
   wpi.ParameterExpression as IndividualExpression,
   wpb.ParameterExpression as BusinessExpression,
   wpd.ParameterExpression as DefaultExpression,
   CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SourceWatchList 
                   WHERE SourceId = @SourceId AND WatchListId = wl.WatchListId)  
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 
   END AS IsActive
FROM 
   [WatchList] wl 
LEFT JOIN  
   SourceWatchList swl ON wl.WatchListId = swl.WatchListId AND swl.SourceId = @SourceId
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT 
        ParameterExpression, SourceId, WatchListId 
    FROM WatchListParameter 
    WHERE EntityType = 'INDIVIDUAL') wpi ON wpi.SourceId = @SourceId 
                                         AND wpi.WatchListId = wl.WatchListId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ParameterExpression, SourceId, WatchListId 
     FROM WatchListParameter 
     WHERE EntityType = 'BUSINESS') wpb ON wpb.SourceId = @SourceId 
                                        AND wpb.WatchListId = wl.WatchListId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ParameterExpression, SourceId, WatchListId 
     FROM WatchListParameter 
     WHERE EntityType = 'DEFAULT') wpd ON wpd.SourceId = @SourceId 
                                       AND wpd.WatchListId = wl.WatchListId
WHERE 
     wl.IsActive = 1
```

I have the above query. Pretty simple.

Here's a snippet from SQL Server Management Studio table :

[image]

and from the debugger in Visual Studio : [image]

The Visual Studio table has no data in the 3 Expression Columns while the Management Studio (correctly) does. Can any tell me why that is, and what steps I can take to resolve the issue?

I'm 100% sure I've used the same parameter between the two as well.

```
string sql = @"SELECT  wl.WatchListId,wl.Code,wl.[Description],wl.DateCreated,
                                wl.CreatedBy,wl.DateModified,wl.ModifiedBy,
                                wpi.ParameterExpression as IndividualExpression,
                                wpb.ParameterExpression as BusinessExpression,
                                wpd.ParameterExpression as DefaultExpression,
                                CASE WHEN EXISTS(Select 1 FROM SourceWatchList 
                                    WHERE SourceId = @SourceId AND WatchListId = wl.WatchListId)  
                                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsActive
                        FROM [WatchList] wl 

                        LEFT JOIN  SourceWatchList swl on wl.WatchListId = swl.WatchListId and swl.SourceId = @SourceId
                        LEFT JOIN (Select ParameterExpression, SourceId, WatchListId FROM WatchListParameter WHERE EntityType = 'INDIVIDUAL') wpi
                                        ON wpi.SourceId = @SourceId AND wpi.WatchListId = wl.WatchListId
                        LEFT JOIN (Select ParameterExpression, SourceId, WatchListId FROM WatchListParameter WHERE EntityType = 'BUSINESS') wpb
                                        ON wpb.SourceId = @SourceId AND wpb.WatchListId = wl.WatchListId
                        LEFT JOIN (Select ParameterExpression, SourceId, WatchListId FROM WatchListParameter WHERE EntityType = 'DEFAULT') wpd
                                        ON wpd.SourceId = @SourceId AND wpd.WatchListId = wl.WatchListId
                        where wl.IsActive = 1";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WatchListCompliance"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourceId", SourceId);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            a.Fill(dt);
        }
```

Comment: Have you triple checked that the connection string you are using in your .NET app is pointing at the same instance/database you are connected to with SSMS?

Comment: @AbeMiessler, sorry I meant to mention that, and yes they are identical

Comment: Can you post your C# code also, even if it may seem redundant to do so?

Comment: sure thing, there it is

Comment: what is the underlying type of these 3 columns? It looks to me like you are trying to store a string holding the value of some expressions to be applied later through some other mechanism, but the SQLDataAdapter is probably interpreting these as actual Expressions and trying to evaluate them, which it obviously can't.  You may need to escape the sequences if you don't want them to be evaluated...

Comment: Try to run sql profiler to see the sql that is being executed against the database from your c# application.

Comment: Perhaps the collation is different...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with types and equality.  You can try using SqlDataType when you define the parameters on the sqlcommand.  When you use addwithvalue without declaring a type it could be selecting the wrong type.  Then you should use the type you declared in the sql expression.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SourceId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
cmd.Parameters["@SourceId"].Value = SourceId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: are you sure your session is configured the same way? Especially the SET ANSI_NULLS option, which changes how comparison behaves with regard to null values.

It is worth noting that some databases may have unusual default values, but some clients (e.g. ADO.NET) explicitely define their own values for the session when they connect, even if you don't ask them to.